# cyclic group and generators

Tags: group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}_{30}$* $= \{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$

The number of elements is $8$ and $8$ is not prime, therefore $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$* is not cyclic.

and the generators are $7,11,13,17,19,23,29$.

can anyone correct me please?

Comment: The fact that the group order is not prime doesn't imply the group is not cyclic.

Comment: You are right that the group is not cyclic, but there certainly are groups cyclic groups of nonprime order, such as the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Comment: You have the implication the wrong way.  If order prime, then cyclic.

Comment: ok i now understand!!! how about the generators which i have listed is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean by generators?  No one element generates the group.  If you allow more than one element then there are certainly redundancies in your list.  For example $7^2 = 49 \equiv 19$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group of prime order must indeed be cyclic. But a group of non-prime order, may or may not be cyclic. For instance $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ is a non-cyclic group of order $4$, while $\mathbb Z_4$ is a cyclic group of order $4$. If the order of the group is not a prime number then you simply don't automatically know if it is prime or not.

Also, your answer says "... therefore $\mathbb Z^*_{30}$ is not cyclic and the generators are $7,11,13...$". This shows that you don't understand what a cyclic group is, or what generators are. A group is cyclic precisely when it has a generator. So, you can't possibly conclude that a group is not cyclic and then immediately present a generator for it.

For an element $a\in \mathbb Z^*_{30}$ to be a generator it must be the case that when you take all powers of $a$, computed in the group $\mathbb Z^*_{30}$ (in which the operation is multiplication modulo $30$ and the identity element is $1$) you get all elements in the group.

So, for instance, the element $29$ is not a generator. Let's check what it does generate: We need to look at $29$, $29,^2$.... But $29^2=841=1$. So all $29$ is going to generate is the subgroup $\{1,29\}$, not the whole group, so $29$ is not a generator of $\mathbb Z^*_{30}$. None of the other elements is a generator, which proves very directly that the group is indeed not cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

By the Chinese remainder theorem,

$$
\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}^*=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^*\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}^*\times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}^*=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.
$$

So you're right, this is not cyclic, but not for the reason you mention.

So no element generates the group.

Edit: I see the confusion. The elements you mention generate $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}^*$.

Comment: Seems likely that the Chinese Remainder theorem probably hasn't been covered for them yet...

Comment: @Jim If the OP was able to compute the units, he/she is probably not that far from the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @julien as it happens I know for a fact that the Chinese remainder theorem was not covered. The aim of this exercise is to get the students to understand the concepts of cyclic group and generators by doing computations directly.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Are you asking me to delete my answer?

Comment: There are answers all over this site which use theorems that haven't been seen by the OP.

Comment: @julien oh not at all (sorry if it came over that way). I'm wanting to make sure some students don't get confused.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Ok, no problem! I understand your point.

Comment: @IttayWeiss You see, all is well. The OP finally accepted the most appropriate answer. And when he/she sees the Chinese remainder theorem, hopefully this will ring a bell.